# disabling scrolling for the whole page when scrolling in an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll

I've got an iframe on my page linking to another page. That one contains a div with a fixed height and overflow:scroll, which works just fine--but when I keep scrolling with the mouse or pad, it scrolls down to the end of the div and then starts to scroll the page--which is annoying.

How can I disable full page scrolling when the mouse is hovering over that div/ the whole iframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us some code for better help. But, basically, set the overflow of the page to hidden onmouseover of your iframe and back to auto onmouseout.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `body {position:fixed}` when hovering and then return that to `body {position: static;}`